# In search for good practices: Mounting disks

Tags: automounting, udisks

I think I did many terrible things at the past, empty directories everywhere, whatever priviledges they had and even mounting a fs inside other mounted fs.

Now I want to make the things right and ask here for opinions for first time. What do you think is the best method to mount your personal data?

I get to come with the idea that dealing with udisksctl should be the right thing, and let it mount my drives in /run/media/user/partition label, I even made a simlink from $HOME  to /run/media/user.

The problem now is that udisksctl mounts partitions with root only priviledges and I don't wan't to mess with chmod and the actual priviledges on the filesystem.

To be honest these are things that I'm doing since years, I'm not new to them but truth is that nobody told me the right way to do it.

What I want to do is to use udisksctl from the terminal to mount my disks in /run/media/myusername and have write access to them.

How do i do it right?

Comment: What is wrong with mounting partitions in `/mnt/some-name` and doing it by a few entries in `/etc/fstab` ?

Comment: @JeremyBoden 1. you-re fighting your desktop environment (in case that you have any), 2. then there is that empty folder somewhere in your system and you don't know why. 3. there you have /run/media/user/ for that reason. 4. you may not always wan't your disks mounted.

I have many disks and as a security reason I don't mount them all the time.

Comment: If a non-root user can mount a physically connected device, then not mounting one is simply a false sense of security "security reason".

Answer (score 3):

UDisks mount function (which is used by most file managers) is mostly meant for temporary mounting of removable devices (it will mount anything, but it's mostly a helper tool to help you to quickly mount a device that you use). If you want to mount the same drives to the same mountpoint with the same mount options you should use `/etc/fstab` it was created for this reason. To answer questions from your comment:

> 1. you-re fighting your desktop environment (in case that you have any)

You are not. All DEs use UDisks which also uses data from `fstab` when mounting device or displaying information about mounted devices. So when DE (un)mounts a device that is referred in `fstab`, mountpoint and options specified there will be used.

> 2. then there is that empty folder somewhere in your system and you don't know why.

That's not a problem. And if you want, you can always check `fstab` to see if a empty folder is a mountpoint.

> 3. there you have `/run/media/user/` for that reason.

Not necessarily, `/run/media/user` is used by UDisks and not even on all systems, it can be configured to mount to a more traditional `/media`, Ubuntu configures UDisks like that.

> 4. you may not always wan't your disks mounted.

In that case, you can use the `noauto` mount option. And mount it at will using the `fstab` configured options and mountpoint. (Even with `udisksctl` or from GUI as mentioned above.)

If you really want to avoid `fstab` and have UDisks 2.9.0 or newer, you can configure it to use [specific mount options per device](http://storaged.org/doc/udisks2-api/latest/mount_options.html) which will allow you to control permissions for non-native filesystems like NTFS and FAT.

There's nothing inherently wrong with not using `fstab`, but using it simply makes more sense for non-removable devices if you want to mount them to a specific location (which I assume you want based on the symlink to your home directory).

Comment: how do I mount a disk with fstab using noauto? Are you sure that my file manager wont mount a disk twice? and anyway, if "UDisks mount function is mostly meant for temporary mounting of removable devices" why do file managers attempt to mount permanent devices there? This is why I thought that udisksctl was the right way. For last if you say that fstab is ok I agree with you. I only want a fast method to mount disks at will on the right place.

Comment: "how do I mount a disk with fstab using noauto?" -- either using `mount` or `udisksctl` or from the file manager. The only difference is that mountpoint and mount options will be taken from `fstab`.

"Are you sure that my file manager wont mount a disk twice" Yes. As I said, file managers also use udisks which knows if the device is mounted and also uses `fstab` to mount it to the mountpoint specified there.

Comment: then I just do 'mount /dev/sdx' without any further options? However whats wrong with mounting at with udisksctl? Because I find it comfortable since I dont have to remove the folder after unmounting, also using default options in the system prevents some errors like having a device mounted by the fm at the default location in case something went wrong with fstab, this is the fight I talked about.